# Flash actionscript 3 find where a video passed to play later from where it is passed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to find the position where a video passed / stopped. So when later loaded need to play from where it previously passed / stopped. I am using flash FLVPlayBack component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you listen for the playheadUpdate event dispatched automatically from the FLVPlayBack component? I've not used that component in years (prefer writing from scratch), but I believe something like this should do the trick (not tested; written off top of my head):

```
private var currentTime:Number = 0;

myFLVPlaybackComponent.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE, playheadUpdated);

private function playheadUpdated(evt:VideoEvent):void {
    currentTime = evt.playheadTime;
}

// next time you want to begin playback, use this (though you may need to convert seconds
// to milliseconds or vice versa, depending on return format, or use seekSeconds())
myFLVPlaybackComponent.seek(currentTime);
```

If you don't have direct control over the playback starting again (in the case of the user hitting the component's 'play' button before you have a chance to tell it to seek()), maybe you can listen for the playingStateEntered event, and if currentTime > 0 (basically, if it's been set previously), immediately seek() to currentTime.

Comment: tnks Tim that helps. I am new to flash video programming. Couldnt find where to start.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you run into any trouble, or need some clarification or understanding about exactly what the above code is doing. The concepts are pretty simple (listening for events, reacting to them), so once you get the hang of it things can really begin to open up.